# Include package in TexLipse

Tags: packages, installing, texlipse

I am using TexLipse on macOS with Eclipse Oxygen. My builder settings are:

[image]

I try to generate a PDF document and get the error:

> LaTeX Error: File `marginnote.sty' not found.

I downloaded the package from CRAN and i am struggling with how to tell TexLipse to use this package.

**How do i import/include a package in TexLipse?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should use `TeX Live Utility` to install packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernard ! I used `TeX Live Utility`to manage my packages and therefore to tell my project in TexLipse how to use this package.